# IdentityServer 6 - Get token within IdentityServer application

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, duende-identity-server

I'm migrating from IdentityServer 3 to IdentityServer 6.

In the IdentityServer 3 application, there was an endpoint where we showed the user's claims including the user's access token. (Our QAs find this useful for testing APIs.)

The IdentityServer 3 application functioned as a client of itself - which is why the token was easily accessible on the ClaimsIdentity. I'm trying to avoid doing that in the new app. However, I still need to display the user's token on the page in the new app.

How can I get the user's access token from within the IdentityServer application itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the `IdentityServerTools.IssueJwtAsync(int, IEnumerable<Claim>)` method. This method generates a JWT based on the provided list of claims. Since I have a valid claims principal based (from cookie auth) in the razor page model, I can plug `this.User.Claims` into that method to generate a JWT that matches the user's identity.

```
public class UserClaims : PageModel
{
    private readonly IdentityServerTools _tools;

    public UserClaims(IdentityServerTools tools)
    {
        this._tools = tools;
    }

    public string Token { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        this.Token = await _tools.IssueJwtAsync(5, this.User.Claims);
    }
}
```